# Sort only the first two elements in each sub-array of 3 elements

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I have an array:

```
list=[[1, 2, 3], [31, 10, 2], [7, 2, 4]]
```

And I want to sort the only the first two elements in each sub-array (in increasing order).

The list should look like this:

```
list=[[1, 2, 3], [10, 31, 2], [2, 7, 4]]
```

The code that I used to do was:

```
list=[[1, 2, 3], [10, 31, 2], [2, 7, 4]]
for i in list:
  if list[0]>list[1]:
    list[0],list[1]=list[1],list[0]
  else:
    print('Do Nothing')
```

Is there any faster way to do it?

Comment: Probably not significantly. Are you running into performance problems with your code?

Comment: If that's a performance bottleneck, you probably should have used some other data-structure in the first place (... maybe). There are probably branchless approaches but it's hard to reason if those are better.

Comment: You could offload this work to `numpy` or `pandas` to speed this up.

Comment: What do you mean by "faster?"

Comment: Will each sublist always have exactly three elements?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this will work as you're only switching around the first two sublists of list. (`list[0]` and `list[1]`, instead of `list[i][0]` and `list[i][1]`)

I would use something like this:

```
list_unsorted = [[1, 2, 3], [31, 10, 2], [7, 2, 4]]
list_sorted = [ [min(i[0], i[1]), max(i[0], i[1]), i[2] ] for i in list_unsorted ]
```

Also, I renamed list to `list_unsorted` as list already is a function in python.

Answer (score 1):

Faster, not without having more context on how the input is obtained, and access to more tools - such as numpy.

But maybe a more pythonic way :

```
alist=[[1, 2, 3, 5], [31, 10, 2], [7, 2, 4]]

def p(l):
  a,b,c=l[0], l[1], l[2:]
  if a>b:
    a,b=b,a
  return [a,b, *c]

print(list(map(p, alist)))
```

This prevents the king of error you maid by using variable "list" instead of variable "i" in your code, as it would be detected by the interpreter.

As a good practice, as list is a python keyword, it should not be used as a variable name.